# Pass variables across Jade template blocks in Express 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am running Express 3.0 with Jade template engine. I'm trying to pass a variable from a template page to the main layout page. Like this:

### layout.jade (snippet):

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en') 
    head 
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        title= locals.title

        - if (typeof(stylesheets) !== 'undefined')
            each stylesheet in stylesheets
                link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/#{stylesheet}.css')

    body
        block body
```

### landing.jade (snippet):

```
stylesheets = ["landing"]
extends layout

block body
    h1 Test 1234
```

The generated code does not include the extra stylesheet tag. I tried `- var stylehseets...` and renaming 'stylesheets' fearing it might be a keyword.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [block append](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a12) feature for this. Straight from the docs is an example exactly like what you are trying to do.

layout.jade

---

```
html
  head
    block head
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/layout.css')
    body
      block body
```

landing.jade

---

```
extends layout

block append head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/landing.css')
block body
  h1 Test 1234
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much cleaner.

Comment: appending to a block works in this case, but what if you really need a variable?

Comment: Just use a variable. There's nothing that says the content of a `block append` section can't use variables or any other feature of jade.